# Obtener texto entre comillas con regex en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

A través de un textarea estoy capturando lo que ingresa el usuario. Mi objetivo es capturar del textarea, todo aquello que se encuentre entre comillas dobles, o comillas simples.
**Nota:** Se asume que no hay saltos de linea si no se han cerrado las comillas.

Por ejemplo, si el textarea contiene lo siguiente:

```
aaa 'bbb' ccc "ddd"
```

Entonces el regex debe capturar

```
bbb
ddd
```

El regex que estoy usando:

```regex
/((\".*?\")|(\'.*?\'))/g
```

Funciona bien para el caso expuesto, sin embargo me arroja un error en consola 
**Unterminated group** cuando el textarea contiene lo siguiente:

```
aaa 'rgba(255,255,255,'
```

Lo que necesito es que toda cadena **sin importar** lo que contenga sea capturada tal y como se capturaron las cadenas del primer ejemplo.

Comment: No sé a qué se debe el error que comentás, probablemente a algo del resto del código, ya que la expresión regular **[funciona bien](https://jsfiddle.net/marianom/zac25rhg/1/)**, sólo que captura las comillas también. -Y la expresión es lo mismo que `/".*?"|'.*?'/g`

Comment: @Mariano Tienes razón. El origen del error sucede cuando obtengo lo que se encuentra entre las comillas, y eso lo ingreso como parámetro en la creación de un objeto Regex.

var interiorcomillas = grupo[2];
var re = new RegExp(interiorcomillas);


Es alli cuando me ocurre el error.

Comment: Para generar un regex a partir de un string, hay que escapar los caracteres especiales, como `var re = new RegExp(interiorcomillas.replace(/[\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))`... pero realmente me pregunto si sería la mejor opción (depende del caso).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Tres formas de capturar el texto entre comillas (simples o dobles)

#### 1. Simple

Para obtener el texto entre comillas simples o dobles, usamos 2 grupos. Luego de la coincidencia, sólo uno de estos 2 grupos tendrá el texto buscado, y usaremos sólo ese valor. Así, se obtiene sólo el texto entre comillas (sin incluir las comillas).

```regex
/"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g
```

```js
function obtenerTextoEnComillas() {
    const regex = /"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)'/g,
       texto = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
    var   grupo,
          resultado = [];
    
    while ((grupo = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
        //si coincide con comillas dobles, el contenido estará en el
        //   grupo[1], con el grupo[2] undefined, y viceversa
        resultado.push(grupo[1] || grupo[2]);
    }
    
    //resultado es un array con todas las coincidencias
    // mostramos los valores separados con saltos de línea
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = resultado.join("\n");
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ingreso" style="width:100%" rows="4">
aaa 'bbb' ccc "ddd"a
aaa 'rgba(255,255,255,'
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Obtener texto entre comillas" onclick="obtenerTextoEnComillas()">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

---

#### 2. Todo en uno

Podemos obtener el texto buscado siempre dentro del mismo grupo (`grupo[2]`).
Al final de la expresión, usamos `\1`, que es una [retroreferencia al grupo 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backreference) (o *[backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)*), para garantizar que termine con el mismo caracter que se capturó al principio (las comillas usadas para abrir).

```regex
/(["'])(.*?)\1/g
```

```js
function obtenerTextoEnComillas() {
    const regex = /(["'])(.*?)\1/g,
       texto = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
    var   grupo,
          resultado = [];
    
    while ((grupo = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
        //el grupo 1 contiene las comillas utilizadas
        //el grupo 2 es el texto dentro de éstas
        resultado.push(grupo[2]);
    }
    
    //resultado es un array con todas las coincidencias
    // mostramos los valores separados con saltos de línea
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = resultado.join("\n");
}
```

```html
Texto:
<textarea id="ingreso" style="width:100%" rows="4">
aaa 'rgba(255,255,255,'
"texto con comillas 'simples' incluidas" ... 'y "viceversa"'
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Obtener texto entre comillas" onclick="obtenerTextoEnComillas()">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

O, permitiendo saltos de línea entre las comillas, reemplazando el punto por `[\s\S]`:

```regex
/(["'])([\s\S]*?)\1/g
```

```js
function obtenerTextoEnComillas() {
    const regex = /(["'])([\s\S]*?)\1/g,
       texto = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
    var   grupo,
          resultado = [];
    
    while ((grupo = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
        //el grupo 1 contiene las comillas utilizadas
        //el grupo 2 es el texto dentro de éstas
        resultado.push(grupo[2]);
    }
    
    //resultado es un array con todas las coincidencias
    // mostramos los valores separados con saltos de línea
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = resultado.join("\n\n");
}
```

```html
Texto:
<textarea id="ingreso" style="width:100%" rows="4">
aaa 'rgba(255,
255,255,'
"texto con comillas 'simples' incluidas" ... 'y "viceversa"'
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Obtener texto entre comillas" onclick="obtenerTextoEnComillas()">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Asimismo, muchas veces se quiere implementar estructuras más elaboradas que `.*?` dentro de las comillas. Esta expresión es apenas menos eficiente que la anterior, pero muchas veces más eficaz con estructuras más complejas (como el regex que se verá luego).

```regex
/(["'])([^"']*(?:(?!\1)["'][^"']*)*)\1/g
```

- Definimos el primer grupo para que coincida con cualquiera de los dos tipos de comillas `(["'])`
- Al final de la expresión, usamos `\1`, como [retroreferencia al grupo 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backreference) (las comillas usadas para abrir).
- En el medio, el grupo 2 `([^"']*(?:(?!\1)["'][^"']*)*)`, que contendrá el texto buscado. Coincide con:

  - cualquier texto sin ninguno de los dos tipos de comillas `[^"']*`, seguido (opcionalmente) de
  - las comillas no capturadas en el grupo 1 `(?!\1)["']`, seguidas de más texto permitido `[^"']*`
    `(?!`..`)` es una [previsión negativa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-look-ahead) (o *[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*).

  *En esta estructura usamos una técnica conocida como *[Unrolling The Loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop)*, que sigue el formato `normal* (?: especial normal* )*`.

---

#### 3. "Con \"escapes\""

También podemos considerar las comillas escapadas con una barra `\"` como válidas (al igual que la mayoría de los lenguajes).
En este caso, usamos el modificador `/y` ([sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)), que obliga a que la coincidencia empiece al inicio del texto o al final de la última coincidencia, y así garantizar que las comillas estén balanceadas. <sup>*ver [compatibilidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)</sup>

```regex
/[^'"\\]*(?:\\.[^'"\\]*)*(["'])([^"'\\]*(?:(?:(?!\1)["']|\\.)[^"'\\]*)*)\1/gy
```

Descripción:

```regex
/
[^'"\\]*                    # Texto antes de las comillas
(?:                         # Grupo sin capturar
    \\.[^'"\\]*             #   Un \escape y más texto
)*                          # repetido 0 o más veces
(["'])                      # Comilla inicial (grupo 1)
(                           # Grupo 2: texto entre comillas
    [^"'\\]*                #   Caracteres que no son comillas ni \
    (?:                     #   Grupo sin capturar
        (?:(?!\1)["']|\\.)  #     Comillas que no son las usadas o un \escape
        [^"'\\]*            #     Seguido de más caracteres permitidos
    )*                      #   repetido 0 o más veces (unrolling the loop)
)                           # fin del grupo 2
\1                          # Cierre de comillas (\1 es el texto capturado en el grupo 1)
/gy                         # Modos: g (todas las coincidencias) y (sticky, anclado)
```

Código:

```js
function obtenerTextoEnComillas() {
    const regex = /[^'"\\]*(?:\\.[^'"\\]*)*(["'])([^"'\\]*(?:(?:(?!\1)["']|\\.)[^"'\\]*)*)\1/gy,
       texto = document.getElementById("ingreso").value;
    var   grupo,
          resultado = [];
    
    while ((grupo = regex.exec(texto)) !== null) {
        //el grupo 1 contiene las comillas utilizadas
        //el grupo 2 es el texto dentro de éstas
        resultado.push(grupo[2]);
    }
    
    //resultado es un array con todas las coincidencias
    // mostramos los valores separados con saltos de línea
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerText = resultado.join("\n");
}
```

```html
Texto:
<textarea id="ingreso" style="width:100%" rows="4">
aaa 'bbb' ccc "ddd"a
aaa 'rgba(255,255,255,'
acá "se \"permiten\" 'comillas' con escapes"
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Obtener texto entre comillas" onclick="obtenerTextoEnComillas()">
<pre id="resultado"></pre>
```

Comment: Hola, he estado intentando volver a combinar el texto extraído y lo que no estaba entre comillas pero no me ha funcionado. ya que lo extraído lo quiero meter entre etiquetas  <sub></sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Prueba hacerlo así**:

```
var str = 'aaa \'bbb\' ccc "ddd" aaa \'b"bb\' ccc "d\'dd"',
  re = /"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/,
  match;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  console.log(match[0]);
  str = str.replace(match[0], '');
}
```

**Salida en consola**:

```
'bbb'
"ddd"
'b"bb'
"d'dd"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(?:'|")(.+)(?:'|")
```

Este te capturara si existe algun contenido interno entre comillas simples o dobles

https://regex101.com/r/ZOLlyd/1

puedes probarlo aqui con todos tus casos

Comment: Esto tiene 3 problemas: **1.** Estás repitiendo `\.`, es decir puntos literales. **2.** Al usar el cuantificador `.+` coincide con cuantos más caracteres se pueda coincidir ([ejemplo](https://regex101.com/r/ZOLlyd/2)). y **3.** La estructura `(?:'|")` es altamente ineficiente, y se debería evitar en favor de `["']`.

Comment: Correcto! lo que no entiendo es como se me colo ese \.