# Dividir una cadena

Tags: c++

Tengo este string:

```
https://insights.ubuntu.com/feed/">Canonical
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener, mediante una función, sólo:

```
https://insights.ubuntu.com/feed/
```

hasta el último slash (borrando `">Canonical`)?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Dado que lo único que te interesa es la cadena antes de las comillas dobles (`"`) tienes un par de opciones.

#### Copiar en otra cadena:

```
const std::string input = "https://insights.ubuntu.com/feed/\">Canonical";
std::string resultado;

std::copy_n(input.begin(), input.find('\"'), std::back_inserter(resultado));
```

Con el código anterior copiarás en el `std::string resultado` toda la cadena original (`input`) hasta las comillas dobles.

#### Modificar la cadena original:

Si en lugar de copiar el contenido en otra cadena prefieres modificar la cadena original puedes hacerlo así:

```
std::string input = "https://insights.ubuntu.com/feed/\">Canonical";
input.resize(input.find('\"'));
```

Con el código anterior, se descartará el contenido de `input` tras las comillas dobles dejando la cadena tal y como la necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Mira esta posible solucion, donde obtenemos la posicion de la palabra a delimitar y en base al constructor de la clase string copiamos desde la posicion cero hasta la n posicion.

```
string filtrarString(string s,string delimitador)
{
    int posDelimitador=s.find(delimitador);
    return string(s,0,posDelimitador);
}


int main()
{

    string url="https://insights.ubuntu.com/feed/>Canonical";
    cout<<filtrarString(url,">Canonical")<<endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te puedes permitir compilar con el estándar C++11 o posterior puedes hacer uso de la librería `regex` para introducir expresiones regulares.

```
std::regex e("<a\\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*?)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");

std::smatch m;
std::string s = "abcd<a href=\"https://insights.ubuntu.com/feed/\">Canonical</a>abcd";

std::regex_search(s,m,e);
if( m.size() > 1 )
  std::cout << "Enlace encontrado: " << m[1] << '\n';
else
  std::cout << "Enlace NO encontrado";
```

Si no, siempre puedes hacer uso de boost (el código es bastante similar)... o incluso puedes hacer la búsqueda manualmente.

Lo más sencillo en este caso sería localizar las comillas de inicio y de final:

```
std::string s = "abcd<a href=\"https://insights.ubuntu.com/feed/\">Canonical</a>abcd";

int pos1, pos2;
pos1 = s.find('\"');
if( pos1 == std::string::npos )
  pos1++;
else
  pos2 = s.find('\"',pos1);

if( pos1 == std::string::npos || pos2 == std::string::npos )
  std::cout << "Url no encontrada\n";
else
  std::cout << s.substr(pos1,pos2-pos1);
```

Comment: Si me permitís, una versión más amplia para cubrir algunos posibles espacios: `e("<a\\b[^>]*\\shref\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a\\s*>")`

Comment: @Mariano si pensé hacer la expresión regular más adaptable... pero claro, entonces tenía que estar pendiente de posibles espacios de más, que la url no tiene por qué ir encerrada entre comillas dobles ... y como que la expresión regular acababa siendo demasiado compleja para el ejemplo. Al final la única característica que se quedó fue la de ignorar todos los atributos anteriores y posteriores a `href`... que lo podía haber eliminado tranquilamente pero se me pasó :)

Comment: Entendí la intención de tu respuesta, y la intención era seguir dentro del mismo alcance. Sé en qué [se puede convertir](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/28074/127), pero me pareció oportuno mencionar lo de los espacios, ya que es muy habitual que existan alrededor del `=` y antes del cierre del tag, intentando no [complicarlo tanto](http://lars.ruoff.free.fr/xmlcpp/).

Comment: @Mariano Jajajaja, buen ejemplo el que has elegido. Es un ejemplo perfecto que demuestra lo complicado que resulta complacer a todo el mundo con la respuesta.

Comment: @Mariano te había entendido perfectamente. Yo también hago recomendaciones en algunas respuestas y eso no condiciona el que se lleven o no un voto por mi parte.

Comment: De hecho, si hay algo para complacer (también en mi recomendación), es cambiar el punto por `[\\s\\S]`  :-)